# Can anyone with enough reputation create tag synonyms hotdeploy and hot-deploy?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I like to make [hotdeploy](/questions/tagged/hotdeploy) and [hot-deploy](/questions/tagged/hot-deploy) synonyms, but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Can anyone with enough reputation make these tags synonyms?